# Inserting From external Data Source to Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive

when we use PolyBase which is sql server 2016 technique
and add an external table to a table in hive 
and we  want to insert data in this external table =>inserting this data in associated hive table
my question is ?
is there any limit in external table max inserted records 
I mean if I am inserting data in external table from another sql server table that has more than 30000 records 
I encountered this error

```
Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQLNCLI11". 110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. 
Details: Exception: Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Common.ExternalAccess.HdfsAccessException, Message: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_DestroyRecordWriter: Error [0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.getDatanodeStorageInfos(DatanodeManager.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.updatePipelineInternal(FSNamesystem.java:6379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.updatePipeline(FSNamesystem.java:6344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.updatePipeline(NameNodeRpcServer.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.updatePipeline(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:971)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
] occurred while accessing external file.
```

while inserting less than 30000 records  leads to every thing works ok and data is inserted in hive
will this error because of one of the reasons

1- there is a limit in external  table insert records number

2- there is a limit in poly base configuration

3- Any other problem in hive

Comment: is hive table partitioned?

Comment: No it is not partitioned